# Exclude or change package used as dependency in rpm package under CentOS

Tags: nginx, centos, rpm, dependencies

I have an RPM package that depends on many other packages, so installing it will install everything I need - quite a normal approach. But one of the packages depends on custom nginx build (general nginx + some extra modules) from 3rd-part repo, which is not supported anymore. The bad part of it is that maintainer named that custom nginx package with some 'custom' name, not just 'nginx' but 'my-nginx').

As I do not use any of the nginx modules I'd better to use nginx.org's nginx package, but of course I can not install 'nginx' as it conflicts with 'my-nginx'. I can only do that by 'force' install.

**Is there any way for me to have nginx as 'my-nginx' so dependency won't be break and system can be updated without complaining on broken packages?**

Thank you!

Comment: You need to either make your own my-nginx build or rebuild the depending package.

Comment: Any way of exclude package from list of dependencies? The original package used to update sometime, so to have it updated I have 2 options: somehow 'mask' or 'exclude' my-nginx on system level so update won't complain if it is not there, or build my own nginx, name it my-nginx, and install. But the nginx used to update too, so I'd better use exclude if it is possible (I don't know how).

Comment: You cannot exclude from dependencies. You could make use of the skip dependencies flag but that would skip ALL dependency checking, not only for that package.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually easy with `rpmrebuild`.

```
yum install epel-release
yum install rpmrebuild
```

Then:

```
rpmrebuild --edit-spec --package /path/to/your/bad.rpm
```

Then edit the autogenerated spec file by renaming package/dependencies as desired. After saving, you will have the new `.rpm` file based on your edits.